# Submit button stay in form after click

Tags: javascript, php, onclick, submit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiIyZ.jpg)**I want to stay in Form view after a click on submit button**
I have a navigation bar with buttons:

```
<div class="bar blueGrey">
  <button class="bar-item button tablink orange" onclick="openNavBarChoise(event,'HomePage')">Home</button>
  <button class="bar-item button tablink" onclick="openNavBarChoise(event,'CVsPage')">CV</button>
  <button class="bar-item button tablink" onclick="openNavBarChoise(event,'ContactPage')">Contact</button>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
function openNavBarChoise(evt, choiceName) {
  var i, x, tablinks;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName('choice');
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName('tablink');
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(' orange', '');
  }
  document.getElementById(choiceName).style.display = 'block';
  evt.currentTarget.className += ' orange';
}
```

when someone click on button Contact go to Contact Form. **I want stay in this Form after click on submit**, but this code return to HomePage.

```
<!--/*************** Begin Contact Page ***************/-->
<div id="ContactPage" class="container border choice" style="display:none">
  <div class="panelChristos00">
      <div class="ImgFPanel">
          <img class="ImgPP" id="imgJob" src="Icons\contactSupport.png" alt="contactSupport" width="80px">
      </div>

      <div id="ergasia" class="firstLine">
          <h2>Form</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="container">


          <form id="form0" method="post" >

              <div class="requiredM00">
                  <p style="color:red"><?php echo $requiredMessage;?></p><p style="color:blue"><?php echo $completeMessage;?></p>
              </div>
              <label for="name">Name <span class="error" style="color:red">*<?php echo $nameErr;?></span></label>
              <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">

              <label for="email">Email <span class="error" style="color:red">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span></label>
              <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">

              <label for="phone">Phone <span class="error" style="color:blue"> <?php echo $phoneErr;?></span></label>
              <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone;?>">

              <label for="subject">Message <span class="error" style="color:red">*<?php echo $subjectErr;?></span></label>
              <textarea id="subject" name="subject" style="height:200px"    ><?php echo $subject; ?></textarea>

              <input type="submit" value="Send">
          </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: then change type submit to button

Comment: @DevsiOdedra then the form will probably simply stop doing anything, there currently doesn’t appear to be anything that would submit the form via AJAX in the background then …

Comment: you wanna stay at the contact form and still send the form, right? you need to use ajax to be able to do that. Like, attach event handler (on submit) to the form and preventDefault the event to prevent its default behaviour (like going back to the homepage)

Comment: @04FS have you any solution?

Answer (score 0):

by default form submit button submit the form to itself to stop this use evt.preventdefault() on form submit button

Comment: Thanks. How can use it in my code? When Press Send stay in this form and run php code.

Answer (score 0):

You wanna stay at the contact form and still send the form, right? you need to use ajax to be able to do that.

Attach event handler (on submit) to the form and preventDefault the event to prevent its default behaviour (like going back to the homepage)

```
var form_el = document.getElementById("form0");

form_el.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // this will prevent the page from going back to homepage

    var form  = new FormData(this);

    var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();

    XHR.open("POST", "server.php", true);

    // response handler
    XHR.onload = function () {
     // do something with the response
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        var userInfo = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      }
    };

    XHR.send(form);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I add this code in my idex.php file and I have changed myForm with form0 and server.php with index.php. I have exactly the same problem. I want stay in form with result from php call. Php code for form is in same file.

Comment: No. I insert this code in my file index.php, who is the form and php code. Could you help me more? how to adapt your code to mine.

Comment: Thanks.When I press the button "send" do nothing.

Comment: I also add an image, who describe better what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this it will take you to new tab like you wanted

```
 <form action="your file name">
        <input type="text">
        <input onclick="e.preventDefault()" type="submit" formtarget="_blank">
 </form>
```

Comment: you can also add target attribute to form tag like this <form target="_blank"></form>

Comment: I don't want new tab. I want stay in same tab, with results of my php code.

Comment: then remove target attribute

Comment: Thanks. Could you look my jpeg, who describe what I want to do.

Comment: then you have to submit your form through an event listener on button and call  api and submit through that and for that use ajax or any other library read this https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp then you dont have to use action in form i dont know about php but in javascript fetch() is for that                       watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ko3cBzW-q8o this might help you sound quality is bad that all i found for you